# ZF2: Where are sessions stored?

Tags: session, zend-framework2

My requirements of Zend\Session are pretty straightforward and my first access to it is with the following line of code:

```
$this->session = new Container('MySession');
```

My question is, where (by default) is this stored?  In the case of ZF1, it was very simple: there was a file for each session under /data/session.  The file name was a cookie id and you could 'cat' the file to see what was going on.

What's the buzz with ZF2?  I've had a look through Zend\Session\Config files but I'm still in the dark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using just `$this->session = new Container('MySession');` then your sessions will by default be saved wherever your php.ini is set to save them. Normal installations set them to be saved in the /tmp folder.

So you have two options:

1) Change the session.save_path in your php.ini to the new location.

2) You can do something like this:

```
$this->session = new SessionConfig();
$this->session->setOptions(array(
    'save_path' => __DIR__ . '/data/session'
));
```

Answer (score 2):

Session data location is not depends on framework. It is in php.ini, option `session.save_path`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didnt find anything under `Zend\Session\Config\StandardConfig` and `Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig`  ?

Also, take a look at  `Zend\Session\Storage`

Then you can configure some stuff as you can read here:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.session.config.html